# What tempo is "frisch und munter"?

Tags: piano, tempo

There are no tempo markings; it just says *frisch und munter*. I can't find anything on it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your piece is from Robert Schumann, who favored (German) descriptions over Italian terms. My dictionary suggests

- bouncy
- fresh as a daisy
- lively

So in any case the should be in the *Allegretto* region and definitely lively.

Answer (score 1):

From [Grove Music Online: Munter](https://doi.org/10.1093/gmo/9781561592630.article.19367):

> (Ger.: ‘merry’, ‘cheerful’, ‘brisk’, ‘vigorous’)
> Perhaps the nearest German equivalent of the Italian Allegro . Schumann used it twice in *Album für die Jugend* op.68: the ‘Soldatenmarsch’ is marked *munter und straff* with the translation *gaio e deciso*, and ‘Fröhlicher Landmann’ has ***frisch und munter***, translated *animato e grazioso*. It is otherwise relatively rare. (boldface mine.)

In the case of "Fröhlicher Landmann" (quarter note equals...):

- [Jörg Demus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vknKgKZvjeQ) = 112.
- [Paul Badura-Skoda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHnejgLHVvk&t=7m16s) = 116.
- [Joseph Nagy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxIfQNCStwg) = 126.
- [Michael Endres](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um8dOgMjrG4) = 132.